# How SenseNet Permission System on The Content Tree

Tags: sensenet

I am still trying to understand how SenseNet permission system works.

For that I read SenseNet wiki pages and done following use case diagram:

[image]

I did not understand "permission tree", "Explicite list", "Effective list" concepts and the visualized trees in the [Permission Queries](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Permission_queries) wiki page.

Could you please explain the example in the wiki page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One permission entry is any permission setting on a content for an identity (user or group). For example: first, you allow the Open permissions on the **/Root/Folder1** for **User1**. This is an ***explicit entry***. In a next step, you allow **Open** permission for the **User2** on the same content. These two setting are two explicit entries what we call **explicit list**. This is similar to Windows ACL.

This list affects the whole subtree because a content's permissions can be inherited from the parent. For example **User1** and **User2** have **Open** permission on the **/Root/Folder1/Document1** but these permissions are inherited
from the **/Root/Folder1**. So the **Document1** has two permission entries even though you did not set anything on this content. These entries are effective entries what we call ***effective list***.

The permission tree is a virtual tree that is the mutation of the big content tree and contains only contents that have explicit permission entries.
In fact, it is an existing object, resides in the permission system internally and it is built for faster evaluation purpose.
It is easier to understand through a content chain. For example you have a document in depth: /Root/Sites/DemoSite/Workspace1/Doclib/Folder/Document1
and the following contents have explicit entries: Root, DemoSite, Doclib, and Document1. Then the permission tree contains only these nodes:
/Root/DemoSite/Doclib/Document1. In this tree, the parent of the Document1 is the Doclib.